# Difference between linux mint LXDE LMDE

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I am new to linux and confused with mint LXDE and mint LMDE

What is the difference between linux mint LXDE and mint LMDE ?

Answer (score 3):

[LXDE](http://lxde.org/) is a [Desktop Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment). I'm presuming that Mint LXDE is a flavor of Mint bundled with LXDE - many distributions (such as Kubuntu) have alternate versions based upon different DE's.

[image: A screenshot of the LXDE Desktop Environment]

---

[LMDE](http://www.linuxmint.com/download_lmde.php) is Linux Mint Debian Edition - it's a version of Linux Mint based upon Debian Testing, designed in part for compatibility.

As for which is better - [well, frankly, that's a question that SuperUser denizens prefer not be asked](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2983/are-questions-of-the-type-which-option-is-better-a-or-b-allowed), because there is not concrete answer.